# Search by company in Enterprise search and add drop down box to list company

Tags: user-profile, enterprise-search, people-search

I'm stuck with these issues in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. 
I have been able to configure a Search Schema to import data from AD company entry. This part works, but I can't search for the company name in people search.

**Example**: I have 5 company entries: mcb,nes,kfc,sbm,361. I can't search in people search by company.

Also I want to create a drop down box in master page search enterprise to select people by department, company, office. Can you please quide how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your search working on the people properties you need to do some more configuration. Once you have imported the user profiles into SharePoint, you need to configure the people search. Refer [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-configure-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013/) link to configure people search. Also, in the search service application, make sure that you have the [managed property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630(v=office.15).aspx) for the property you want to search on. [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.15).aspx) link will help you understand how to create/modify managed properties.